# Possible to increase the RAM on a MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a 13" MacbookAir with 4GB of RAM and I was interested in adding some more RAM.  I have heard some people say that this cannot be done on the Air.

Is it possible to add more RAM to a MacBook Air?

Answer (score 2):

No, the RAM is soldered onto the motherboard to save space.